# Календарь java с автозаполнением ячеек с днями

Tags: java, calendar

Нужно реализовать генерацию графика работы на текущий месяц. Имеется, например, 8 работников. Нужно что бы каждый как минимум 1 раз работал в выходной, остальные рабочие дни в будни. Т.е. требуется отобразить календарь за текущий месяц и рандомно заполнить его кто когда работает. Как отобразить календарь - понятно, в принципе, даже как определить рандомно кто когда работает - я примерно понимаю. Вопрос, можно ли для каждой ячейки календаря присвоить какой-то АЙДИ? Что бы заставить выводить в эту ячейку данные. Или надо просто самому рисовать таблицу для каждого месяца?
Можно как-то сделать вывод рандомного массива с цифрами от 1 до 8, с повторением не больше 5 раз для каждой цифры?

Comment: `Можно как-то сделать вывод рандомного массива с цифрами от 1 до 8, с повторением не больше 5 раз для каждой цифры?` это легко. Например создать list в который полижить каждое число от 1 до 8 5 раз и потом сделать Collection.shuffle.

Comment: если хочется присвоить уникальный id то воспользуйтесь java.util.UUID для объектов ячейки

Comment: А id="20160425" (25 Апр. 2016) не достаточно уникальное для календаря?

Comment: Вопрос был не в том, какой ID придумать для ячейки, а как его присвоить в принципе ячейке календаря.

Comment: ну так смотрите, добавьте классу Ячейка поле типа UUID uuid и в конструкторе класса добавьте UUID this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID(). либо как посоветовал @SergeyMitrofanov - используйте в качестве id саму дату - она уж точно будет уникальна =) Добавьте геттеры и сеттеры для этого поля и вот вам уникальный идентификатор для каждого объекта типа Ячейка

Comment: @pavel, подскажи плз, я сделал так List kto = new ArrayList();
                kto.add(1);
                kto.add(2);
                kto.add(3); Затем перемешал числа Collections.shuffle(kto);  Как мне потом обратиться к первому, например, по счету числу?

Comment: @batman эм... kto.get(0) ?

Comment: @pavel спасибо, пытался все сделать гораздо сложнее и не получалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте поле UUID в класс, отвечающий за вашу ячейку. Это будет отличный идентификатор для ваших целей.

```
public class yourCell {
   ...
   public UUID uuid;

   public yourCell(...) {
      ...
      uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
   }

   ...
}
```

Можно реализовать, как посоветовал @Sergey Mitrofanov - генерирование идентификатора в зависимости от даты.